# Apache Beam - using custom classes with generic types and coders

Tags: java, avro, apache-beam

I am a beginner user of Apache Beam. I had no problems implement the logic for my aggregations, I am just a bit annoyed by not being able to use abstract types in my custom classes.

I have some custom classes that are used as input/output to `PTransforms`. In these classes I would like to use abstract types like e.g. `Set<String>` instead of `HashSet<String>` but I can't, at least using the `AvroCoder`. Is there any other way to specify a coder that automatically supports these type of classes or do I need to specify my own coder.

Example class:

```
@DefaultCoder(AvroCoder.class)
public class WordStatistics {
  public String key;
  public Set<String> displays;
}
```

Exception by using `Set` instead of `HashSet`

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.util.Set.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData.newInstance(SpecificData.java:347)
    at org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectDatumReader.newArray(ReflectDatumReader.java:100)
    at org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectDatumReader.readArray(ReflectDatumReader.java:133)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:177)
    at org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectDatumReader.readField(ReflectDatumReader.java:302)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:222)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:175)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:153)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:145)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.AvroCoder.decode(AvroCoder.java:317)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.Coder.decode(Coder.java:159)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.KvCoder.decode(KvCoder.java:82)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.KvCoder.decode(KvCoder.java:36)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.CoderUtils.decodeFromSafeStream(CoderUtils.java:115)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.CoderUtils.decodeFromByteArray(CoderUtils.java:98)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.CoderUtils.decodeFromByteArray(CoderUtils.java:92)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.CoderUtils.clone(CoderUtils.java:141)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.MutationDetectors$CodedValueMutationDetector.<init>(MutationDetectors.java:113)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.MutationDetectors.forValueWithCoder(MutationDetectors.java:44)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.ImmutabilityCheckingBundleFactory$ImmutabilityEnforcingBundle.add(ImmutabilityCheckingBundleFactory.java:112)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.ParDoEvaluator$BundleOutputManager.output(ParDoEvaluator.java:260)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:309)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$700(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:77)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:621)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFnOutputReceivers$WindowedContextOutputReceiver.output(DoFnOutputReceivers.java:71)
    at com.unsilo.transforms.FromAccumulatorToStatsMapper.processElement(FromAccumulatorToStatsMapper.java:14)
    at com.unsilo.transforms.FromAccumulatorToStatsMapper$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:275)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:240)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.beam_runners_direct_java.runners.core.SimplePushbackSideInputDoFnRunner.processElementInReadyWindows(SimplePushbackSideInputDoFnRunner.java:78)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.ParDoEvaluator.processElement(ParDoEvaluator.java:207)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DoFnLifecycleManagerRemovingTransformEvaluator.processElement(DoFnLifecycleManagerRemovingTransformEvaluator.java:55)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectTransformExecutor.processElements(DirectTransformExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectTransformExecutor.run(DirectTransformExecutor.java:124)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Can you share the full stack trace?

Comment: Updated the stack trace

Comment: Did you find how to use Set instead of HashSet ?

Comment: No, sorry, I actually moved from Beam to Spark because I couldn't do what I wanted in Beam (maybe my own fault/lack of knowledge)